# Why is React.forwardRef preventing this HOC from rendering when context updates?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I came across this behavior while working on [this epic react lesson](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-performance/blob/main/src/final/06.extra-3.js), and after re-reading the react docs on both `forwardRef` and `HOCs` cannot figure out why this would be happening.

I've cut the epic react lesson down below to demonstrate what I am seeing.  Basically, it's an `AppProvider` component providing access to the global state through context, then the `withStateSlice` `HOC` retrieves the correct slice of state and injects it into the `state` prop of the `Cell` components.

The weird behavior I'm seeing is when the `withStateSlice` `HOC` calls `forwardRef` on the wrapped component:

`return React.memo(React.forwardRef(Wrapper))`

the profiler shows that only the one `Cell` that was clicked actually rendered.

[image: Profile With React.forwardRef]

If I remove `forwardRef` from the above so we are left with this:

`return React.memo(Wrapper)`

then I am seeing all the `Cell` `HOC` components rendering, which from what I understand of context should be the expected behavior.

[image: Profile Without React.forwardRef]

From what I've read this it doesn't seem like `forwardRef` should affect rendering when context changes but I could be wrong.  This is with `React 17.0.2` and I am seeing the same behavior in development and production builds (with profiling turned on using: `react-scripts build --profile`

```
import * as React from 'react'

const AppStateContext = React.createContext()
const AppDispatchContext = React.createContext()

function appReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_CELL': {
      const newState = [...state];
      newState[action.i] = state[action.i] + 1;
      return newState 
    }
    default: {
      throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: ${action.type}`)
    }
  }
}

function AppProvider({children}) {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(appReducer, [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5])
  return (
    <AppStateContext.Provider value={state}>
      <AppDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </AppDispatchContext.Provider>
    </AppStateContext.Provider>
  )
}

function useAppState() {
  const context = React.useContext(AppStateContext)
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useAppState must be used within the AppProvider')
  }
  return context
}

function useAppDispatch() {
  const context = React.useContext(AppDispatchContext)
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useAppDispatch must be used within the AppProvider')
  }
  return context
}

function fibonacci(n) {
  return n < 1 ? 0
       : n <= 2 ? 1
       : fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)
}

function withStateSlice(Comp, slice) {
  const MemoComp = React.memo(Comp)
  function Wrapper(props, ref) {
    const state = useAppState()
    return <MemoComp ref={ref} state={slice(state, props)} {...props} />
  }
  Wrapper.displayName = `withStateSlice(${Comp.displayName || Comp.name})`
  return React.memo(React.forwardRef(Wrapper)) // return React.memo(Wrapper)
}

function Cell({state: cellValue, i}) {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
  const handleClick = () => dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_CELL', i})

  // Artificial slowdown for better visibility in profiler
  for (let n = 10; n < 20; n++) {
    fibonacci(n);
  }

  return (
    <button
      className="cell"
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
      {Math.floor(cellValue)}
    </button>
  )
}
Cell = withStateSlice(Cell, (state, { i }) => state[i])

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="grid-app">
      <div>
        <AppProvider>
          <Cell i={0} />
          <Cell i={1} />
          <Cell i={2} />
          <Cell i={3} />
          <Cell i={4} />
          <Cell i={5} />
        </AppProvider>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: I should note this isn't changing the behavior of the `App` at all, and from a performance standpoint using `React.forwardRef` seems to be desired since only one Cell is rendering vs the 6 Cell wrappers.  Another though I had is the could potentially just be an issue with the react profiler but not sure on that

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Problem

It's like a bug in devtools when you put `React.forwardRef` inside `React.memo`. Therefore, to know whether these `Cell`s are really re-render or not, you can put `console.log()` inside `Wrapper` and then click `Cell`.

#### 2. Some topics about this

I get some details about this topic but it still has not been solved.

- [vasilii-kovalev create issue in react](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20139)
- [kentcdodds answer about this question](https://kentcdodds.com/calls/01/25/why-is-forward-ref-required-to-limit-re-renders)